# defer or timeout on directive?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Ive been looking at some defer and watch examples but finding it hard to relate to my code (think I may have set it up wrong). Essentially I have a directive that returns some web-service content, in this content there is an jquery "read more" which I need to activate.

But I think the read more is being run before the content is in the page so not working. Ie if I put a $timeout around the read-more init with an 3 sec wait it works, but just setting an arbitrary time value is bad practice right?

```js
nccaApp.directive('glossary', ['dataFactory', '$http', '$timeout', '$location', function (dataFactory, $http, $timeout, $location) {

    return function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl, transclude) {

        strURL = "/glossary/glossaryService.aspx?CategoryID=" + attrs.categoryid;

        var location = window.location.href;


            $http.get(strURL, { cache: true }).success(function (data) {

                element.html(dataFactory.glossaryText(element.html(), data))

                    // Init readmore here
                    var lesslink = 'Read less';
                    var moreLink = 'Read more';

                    $("article.read-more").readmore({
                        lessLink: '<a href="#">' + lesslink + '</a>',
                        moreLink: '<a href="#">' + moreLink + '</a>'
                    });


            });


    }


}

]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are right that using `$timeout` to work around timing issues is a hack. Can you try this and see if it helps?

```
element.find("article.read-more").readmore({
  lessLink: '<a href="#">' + lesslink + '</a>',
  moreLink: '<a href="#">' + moreLink + '</a>'
});
```

Also, you may have a reason for setting the element's html, but generally in Angular it is preferred to run the data through a template. It could be another potential cause for the problem you are seeing.

Comment: no sure what you mean, its the activation thats not happening in right order, ie $("article.read-more").readmore( etc, I need to run this after I think